# Codename one: Getting error while establishing connection with server having SSL certificates on Android

Tags: codenameone

Getting below error while establishing connection

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative names present in android

I am trying to connect to the server using "https" instead of "http" from Android device.

Comment: Does your server have a valid SSL certificate? And when you visit the URL from your browser, there are no security issues?

Comment: No, We have self signed certificate .

Comment: When I trying to connect from browser  then getting error " Your connection is not private
Attackers might be trying to steal your information from 111.235.52.250 (for example, passwords, messages, or credit cards). Learn more
NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should buy a valid certificate from a trusted CA, or use an alternative solution such as Let's Encrypt

Answer (score 2):

For https to work, your browser should show either a padlock and green **Secure** text or the `https` itself turns green.

Check with your certificate provider to see if it's valid.

Self-signed certificates may not work as expected.

Comment: What should I do for self signed certificates?